# Problem loading resources from classpath

Tags: java, tomcat, path

In a web application running in a local tomcat, I am trying to load a folder `/folder` which is in `tomcat/webapps/myproject/WEB-INF/folder` 
To do it:

```
InputStream realPath = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/folder");
```

Which returns `null`. This piece of code is supposed to load resources from classpath, which is if I am not wrong in the path where my folder is in.
Anyway, I moved my folder to different paths, such as `tomcat/webapps/myproject/WEB-INF/classes/folder` or `tomcat/webapps/myproject/WEB-INF/lib/folder` with the same result.
Did I miss something? Thanks in advance.

**Regarding on all your answers (thanks), I edit my question with all I have tryed, with the same null result.**
A)

```
 String realSource = getServletContext().getRealPath("/folder");
```

B)

```
InputStream realPath = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/folder/fileInFolder");
```

C)

```
ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext)context.getExternalContext().getContext();
String realSource = servletContext.getRealPath("/folder");
```

I must say that my `folder` path is `tomcat/webapps/myproject/WEB-INF/classes/folder`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that /WEB-INF is not in the CLASSPATH of a WAR file.

/WEB-INF/classes is in the CLASSPATH; so are all the JARs in /WEB-INF/lib.

If you put the file you need into /WEB-INF/classes the WAR class loader should be able to find it.

You cannot read a directory that way.  It must be a file.

UPDATE:

> Anyway, I moved my folder to different
>   paths, such as
>   tomcat/webapps/myproject/WEB-INF/classes/folder
>   or
>   tomcat/webapps/myproject/WEB-INF/lib/folder
>   with the same result. Did I miss
>   something?

Yes, you've missed two things:

1. Your folder should go in one place - under /WEB-INF/classes
2. You cannot access the folder using getResourceAsStream() and read all the contents.  It doesn't work that way.  You can only read one individual file that way.

Comment: You can't, and you shouldn't.

Comment: And there is no other way to get the path of this folder?? Apart from ServletConfig.getRealPath() ?? I wanted to do it in this way, because before gave me problems also.

Comment: The better question is: what are you trying to do?  I know you want to get the path of the folder and read the contents; how many files and for what purpose?  What are you doing with those files?

Comment: I want to send this folder path to another function which will process every file in this folder (the number will be different each time, maybe 10, maybe 1000). But I want to no dependn on what machine I am using, so I want to have this resources in my tomcat. Thanks

Comment: What's in the folder?  How do those files get there?  Are you triggering this via the servlet through an HTTP request?  Or s it a regularly scheduled job that you want performed every day?  If it's the latter, I don't think a web app is the right way to go.  A Quartz or cron job would be a better idea.  I'm not sure that this belongs on a web server.

Comment: It will be run when the user want, using this webapp interface, so cron is not the solution. In the folder will be some videos that the user will upload somehow using another service. Thanks

Comment: So the user can access all the videos in the folder, even those that don't belong to them?  Your use case seems muddled to me.

Comment: Not really, admin will be able to call this function to make some process to all the videos in this folder. Normal users just will be able to upload and we will save in this same folder. SO I just need to get the path of it to can process with other functions the videos there.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the full path of the folder within your webapp so that you can use File operations on it, here is a way to do it.

Note: myfolder is parallel to WEB-INF within my webapp

```
String relativeWebPath = "/myfolder";
String absoluteDiskPath = getServletContext().getRealPath(relativeWebPath);
```

Now printing out `absoluteDiskPath` gives me

```
D:\apache-tomcat-6.0.20\webapps\mywebapp\myfolder
```

Try listing files in that folder by

```
File dir = new File(absoluteDiskPath); 

String[] children = dir.list(); 
if (children != null) 
{ 

    for (int i=0; i<children.length; i++) { 
    // Get filename of file or directory 

    String filename = children[i]; 
    System.out.println("filename no " + i + filename);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had tryed before this way, but I had problems to init the Servlet, that's why I decided to change my way. The problem I had was in this cast Servlet servlet = (Servlet) context.getExternalContext();

Comment: Can you make 
String absoluteDiskPath = getServletContext().getRealPath(relativeWebPath);
 without problems??

Comment: @mujer esponja: yes, if your code is a proper servlet (i.e. extending HTTPServlet) then you can directly use getServletConfig() and getServletContext() in the goGet() method http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html

Comment: I edited my question, because I am getting the same null result

Answer (score 0):

Remove the leading slash and try i.e.

```
InputStream realPath = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("folder");
```

Comment: I tryed also, with the same result. Thanks